# el.bind is not a function Error in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using creating costume directive in angularjs. I want to scroll the window on click to `data-target` element. but its showing the error `el.bind is not a function`

in custome directive code as bellow,

```
'use strict';

app.directive("productfinderpage", ["$window","$document", function($window, $document) {
    console.log("enter into directive");
    return {
        restrict: "AC",
        link: function () {


            // get all anchors

            var anchors = angular.element(document.querySelectorAll("a[data-target]"));


            angular.forEach(anchors, function (el) {
                el.bind("click", function (e) {
                    var targetLink = e.target.dataset.target;
                    var targetContext = angular.element(document.querySelector("[data-name=\"" + targetLink + "\""));
                    var targetContextInt = targetContext.offsetTop;
                    // initiate scroll
                    scrollTo(scrollable, targetContextInt, 225);
                });
            });


            // scroll to function
            function scrollTo(element, to, duration) {
                if (duration <= 0) return;
                var difference = to - element.scrollTop;
                var perTick = difference / duration * 10;

                setTimeout(function () {
                    element.scrollTop = element.scrollTop + perTick;
                    if (element.scrollTop == to) return;
                    scrollTo(element, to, duration - 10);
                }, 10);
            }

        }
    };
}]);
```

html code as bellow,

```
<div productFinderPage class="modal-body">
    <div class="info" data-sticky="data-sticky">
        <div class="info-inner">
            <div class="lender-image">LOGO</div>
            <div class="package-name"></div>
            <div class="cta">
                <button class="primary">Add to Favorites</button>
            </div>
            <nav>
                <ul class="info-section">
                    <li><a href="#" data-target="basicInfo">Basic Information</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" data-target="extInfo">Extended Information</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" data-target="loanSize">Loan Size / LVR</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" data-target="loanFees">Loan Fees</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" data-target="services">Services</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="main-details">
        <div class="panel" data-name="basicInfo">
            <div class="panel-header">Basic Information</div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel" data-name="extInfo">
            <div class="panel-header">Extended Information</div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel" data-name="loanSize">
            <div class="panel-header">Loan Size</div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel" data-name="loanFees">
            <div class="panel-header">Loan Fees</div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel" data-name="services">
            <div class="panel-header">Services</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9owtoyL0/) is here.

Comment: `.bind` may be deprecated, use `.on` instead

Comment: jsbin or fiddle pls

Comment: added the fiddle @Bowofola

Comment: @alka add a working jsfiddle pls :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you iterate through an angular element, you get the plain document elements which need to be converted to an angular element again:

```
var anchors = angular.element(document.querySelectorAll("a[data-target]"));

angular.forEach(anchors, function(ele) {
     var el = angular.element(ele);
     el.bind("click", function(e) {
         ..
     });
}
```

See [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9owtoyL0/1/)